# Custom threshold for each host on Icinga2

Tags: centos6, icinga

Just installed Icinga2 2.3.2. Trying to find a way to set different threshold on process for each host. Any help?

Comment: what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below variable in host definition:

```
vars.procs_warning = 400
vars.procs_critical = 500
```

Comment: Thank you. I assume those definition should be on a host file uner Master server. ( /etc/icinga2/repository.d/hosts/client host/procs.conf). Then restart icinga2 service on master server. If my assumption is right, it doesn't work. Did I miss something?

Comment: After applying above host definition into client, it is starting to work. Is that the way it should be done? Thank you.

Comment: Since you are updating configs on each node, then syncing configs with master you are doing right.